# cannot display the result of each one of my function

Tags: c++, function, recursion, iteration

I wrote a code that computes the sum of components of an array which is randomly filled with values between 0 and 1. I have to write two functions, one is iterative, and the other one is recursive. Both should do the same work. The two functions I wrote work fine when I call only one at the time. However, if i try to call the two functions in the main, I can see the result of one only, but cannot see the result from the other one. In addition, my recursive function tends to get called one extra time. I have noticed that if I put getch() as comment in recursive_function(). I know I am missing something, but I cannot figure that out. Thanks for your help. here is the code. i am using Dev-C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

//headers of the thre functions
int random_value(int array[], int size);
int iterative_function (int array[], int size, int sum);
int recursive_function ( int size, int array[], int index, int sum);



int main()
{     
   int size;int array[size]; int sum=0;
   int index=0;
   cout<<"enter the size of the array"<<endl;
   cin>>size;                //enter the size ofthe array...
   random_value(array, size);
   iterative_function (array, size, sum); 
   recursive_function ( size, array, index, sum);
   getch();
   return 0;
}

int random_value(int array[], int size)
{  cout<<"here is the value returned by rand()"<<endl;
   for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
   { array[i]=( rand() % (0-2));
     cout<<array[i]<<endl;
   }
}

int iterative_function (int array[], int size, int sum)
{
   int i,j, number, value; i=0;
   cout<<"from the iterative function"<<endl;
   cout<<"------"<<endl;
   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
   sum=sum+array[i];
   cout<<"sum of the array="<<sum<<endl;           
   getch();
   return 0;      //exit the function. Program terminated succesfully.
}

int recursive_function ( int size, int array[], int index, int sum)
{
  if(size>index)
  {  
    sum=sum+array[index];
    index++;
    recursive_function( size, array, index, sum); 
  }
  cout<<"from the recursive function"<<endl;
  cout<<"------"<<endl;
  cout<<"new sum= "<< sum<<endl;

  getch();
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Just a note: You forget to reset the `sum` variable to zero between calling your two functions.

Comment: note: debugger/tracing is your friend...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Note: Unit testing is your friend.

Comment: I reset the sum variable to zero, and now, i can have the result of each function. Thanks Joachim.

Comment: @Karoly / Peter - <insert_random_name> wants to be your friend. Accept? Yes/No (sorry, couldn't resist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
```

`<conio.h` is not a standard header, i.e. it is not available with all compilers, and you don't need it.

To see the result output of your program:

- run it from the command line, or
- in Visual Studio run it via keypress [Ctrl F5] (no debugging), or
- set a breakpoint on the closing brace of `main`, and run it under a debugger (in Visual Studio e.g. via keypress [F5]).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

As far as I can see you’re not using anything from this header. However, it does provide the symbolic constants `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`, which are intended for `return` statement in `main`. E.g., it can be more clear to write `EXIT_SUCCESS` there than to write `0`, because many folks misunderstand what `0` means in this context.

```
using namespace std;
```

This is OK for a short program or within a namespace.

However, keep in mind that short programs very often end up as not-so-short programs.

And then a `using namespace std;` can easily cause name collisions, in particular with the name `std::distance`.

```
//headers of the thre functions
int random_value(int array[], int size);
int iterative_function (int array[], int size, int sum);
int recursive_function ( int size, int array[], int index, int sum);
```

Although it is partly a matter of preference, there is no *advantage* in forward-declaring the functions before `main`, it is *more work*, and it sometimes causes *problems* when the forward declarations don’t quite match the definitions – as with any unnecessary redundancy, violations of the **DRY** principle (Don’t Repeat Yourself).

Instead, just place the function definitions before `main`.

That way it is also much easier to see what refers to what, because functions that are used by others then necessarily come before those other functions.

```
int main()
{     
   int size;int array[size]; int sum=0;
```

This should not compile, because in C++ only a dynamically allocated array can have a size that is unknown at compile time.

However, C99 supports “variable length arrays” a.k.a. VLAs with the above syntax, and as a language extension the g++ compiler supports that.

On the third and gripping hand, even with the g++ language extension the above declares an array of *indeterminate length*, because the `size` variable has not been initialized and has an indeterminate value.

With the g++ compiler that value is most likely 0, but it can easily be any other value.

To turn off the g++ VLA language extension, and some other language extensions, use the following g++ options:

> ```
> -pedantic -std=c++0x -Wall
> ```

For standard C++, instead of a C99 VLA you should use a C++ `std::vector<int>`.

In order to get a declaration of the `std::vector` class template, include the standard library header `<vector>`.

```
   int index=0;
   cout<<"enter the size of the array"<<endl;
   cin>>size;                //enter the size ofthe array...
```

When you're using a `std::vector`, then here, knowing its size, would be the place to declare that vector.

Or, if declared earlier, here would be the place to resize it.

```
   random_value(array, size);
```

This would better be a function that *returned* a vector of random values.

You would then use that to initialize the declared vector.

```
   iterative_function (array, size, sum); 
   recursive_function ( size, array, index, sum);
   getch();
```

Regarding the `getch()` call, see the above comments about `<conio.h>`.

```
   return 0;
```

Regarding the value `0` here, see the above comments about `<stdlib.h>`.

```
}

int random_value(int array[], int size)
{  cout<<"here is the value returned by rand()"<<endl;
   for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
   { array[i]=( rand() % (0-2));
```

Here you have **Undefined Behavior**, accessing elements of a possibly zero-size array.

```
     cout<<array[i]<<endl;
   }
}

int iterative_function (int array[], int size, int sum)
{
   int i,j, number, value; i=0;
   cout<<"from the iterative function"<<endl;
   cout<<"------"<<endl;
   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
   sum=sum+array[i];
```

Here you are again invoking Undefined Behavior, often called just “UB”, by accessing non-existing array elements.

In addition, even if the array had been of non-zero size, it has not been initialized and so would contain just zeroes or arbitrary values (by the Holy Standard called “indeterminate values”).

```
   cout<<"sum of the array="<<sum<<endl;           
   getch();
```

See the above comment about `<conio.h>`.

```
   return 0;      //exit the function. Program terminated succesfully.
}
```

There is no point in letting the above function always return the same value. From an information-theoretical perspective, that return value carries zero bits of information. Instead just let the function’s result value be `void`.

```
int recursive_function ( int size, int array[], int index, int sum)
{
  if(size>index)
  {  
    sum=sum+array[index];
    index++;
    recursive_function( size, array, index, sum); 
  }
```

Instead of incrementing the `index`, which is non-idiomatic and therefore difficult to spot for experienced readers, just use `index + 1` in the recursive call.

It is a good idea to add `const` to just about every declaration where it is possible.

That would, for example, have forced you to use `index + 1`. :-)

```
  cout<<"from the recursive function"<<endl;
  cout<<"------"<<endl;
  cout<<"new sum= "<< sum<<endl;

  getch();
```

See the above comment about `<conio.h>`.

```
  return 0;
```

See the above comment about function always returning the same value.

```
}
```

Summing up, with all the Undefined Behavior it is just happenstance if things appear to work.

Fix the UB's (in particular replace C99 VLA with `std::vector`) first of all, then perhaps ask new question if it still does not work as it should. ;-)

Comment: Ok, I will fix those errors as you suggested. thanks for the deep and great analysis. But I still have the same display multiple times with the recursive function. I can't see what I did wrong, but i know something is not right in my code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You create your array using size but it's initialized AFTER that. You simply get **random** stuffs...
Declare int pointer, read size, allocate the array with `new` then try again (do not forget to `delete`).

Answer (score 0):

First of all the array that you've declared is of unknown size, declare the array after getting input for size

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in recursive_function() it calls itself many times - and *every* time it is called (either by main() or by itself) it will run *all* commands in its body (since you never return early)... *now* can you see a problem with the getch() in there?

Comment: I still don't see the problem with getch() in the recursive function. I thought that the if(size>index) in the recursive function should handle that issue by avoiding the recursive function to call itself more than expected.

Comment: It's not that it causes the function to be called more than expected - it's that *every* time it gets called it waits for a keypress, instead of finishing all of its recursions first and then waiting for one keypress at the end, which is what I suspect you wanted.

Comment: Exact, but even when  I get ride of getch(), i still have the same display multiple times, when actually i would like to have only one display after all the recursions happened.

Comment: Rather than try and display the result from within each function, why not have the functions return the sum, and have the main code display those results? When calling recursive_function() from within itself, you can simply ignore what it returns - it's only the one called by main() that cares what sum it returns.

Comment: It is a good idea, but the second part of the assignment ask us to measure the difference in execution time of each function. That's why I would like to have the result within each function, then I will compute and compare their execution time.

Comment: OK, then if you only want to display the result for the outermost call to recursive_function(), then think about the other variables you pass in to the function... one of them will be zero for the very first call (= the outermost call), but non-zero for every recursed call. Use that to limit when you display the result.